# How can I animate an iCarousel item before getting "unlocked" in Swift+SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uiimage, icarousel

I'm using iCarousel in my game where you can unlock/select different items in it. 
And I would like to add a little animation of shaking or something before the item gets unlocked/changes its state.

Is this possible using iCarousel?

My iCarousel code is located in the GameViewController, so I can't access to a runAction method in there. Besides, the item is a UIImage, I would need to animate a UIImage for certain amount of seconds, and then unlock it. Should I do that in the GameViewController?

I call unlockItem() from the MainMenu using NSNotification.
I thought I could just make a SKSpriteNode of the selected item and animate it in the SKScene but, when I try to do that, there's nothing I can do to make the Sprite be above the iCarousel.

If you can give me any hints or little pieces of code on how to achieve this, I would appreciate it. I'm not asking for a life saving code, just an idea of what I can do to achieve it.